# How can I fit an image to a rectangle in visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, image-editing

I'd like to make a rectangle in visio that behaves as though it has `background-size: cover` applied. This means that the image is used as a texture, and resized to cover the entire rectangle, while preserving the aspect ratio of the image.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/m3jbkaup/embedded/result/) an example of how things should look.

Comment: Your example does not preserve the aspect ratio, it just centers and crops the original image to fit the smallest dimension.  Are you saying that is your goal or that is the problem?

Comment: Maybe my definition of aspect ratio is wrong - what I meant is "scaled isotropically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at custom fill patterns, try this article for a start:

[How to create a custom fill pattern by using a bitmap image in Visio](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295411)

Comment: Worked this out myself in the end, but thanks anyway! (needs the developer ribbon in visio 2013)